# How to make http post request in Angular 4 Universal?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, nodemailer, angular-universal

I am working on **Angular 4 Universal**, I am trying to send email for contact form using `nodemailer`. I am not able to post the data through `http.post`

***contact.template.html***

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <input type="text" name="fullname"  (keyup)="validate()" [class.requireds]="isNameInvalid"  placeholder="Full Name" required [(ngModel)]="contactObj.userName" />
      <input type="text" name="email" (keyup)="validate()"  [class.requireds]="isEmailInvalid" placeholder="Email" required  [(ngModel)]="contactObj.userEmail"/>
  </form>
```

***contact.component.ts***

```
contactObj = {
userName: "",
userEmail: "",
};


onSubmit() {
   if (this.isNameInvalid || this.isEmailInvalid) {
   return;
  } else {

    let params = JSON.stringify(this.contactObj);
    let headers = new Headers({"Content-Type": "application/json"});
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    this.http.post("/api/send", params, options).subscribe(res => {
    });
  }
}
```

***server.ts***

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import * as express from 'express';
import * as compression from 'compression';
import { platformServer, renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { ServerAppModule } from './app/server-app.module';
import { ngExpressEngine } from './modules/ng-express-engine/express-engine';
import { ROUTES } from './routes';


const app = express();
const port = Number(process.env.PORT || 8080);

app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: ServerAppModule
}));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', 'src');

app.post("/api/send", sendMailApi);

app.use(compression());
app.use('',express.static('dist'));    
app.use('/assets',express.static('dist/assets'));

app.use('/static',express.static('dist/static', {
  index: false
}));

app.listen(port,() => {
    console.log(`Listening at ${port}`);
});
```

***api.ts***

```
// For send Mail
export function sendMailApi(req, res) {
 console.log(req.body.userName); //returns undefined

let mailTo = {

 from: '"Contact Us" <foo@foo.com>',
 to: "bhushan.foo@foo.com",
 subject: "Foo- Reach out to us",
 html: "Message Body:<p>my message goes here</p>",
 replyTo: req.body.userEmail
};

let smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
 host: "smtp.gmail.com",
 port: 465,
 secure: true,
 auth: {
  user: "foo@foo.com",
  pass: "foo@foo"
 }
});

smtpTransport.sendMail(mailTo, function (error, info) {
  if (error) {
   console.log("Error sending mail: %s", error);
  } else {

   console.log("Message sent: " + info.messageId, info.response);
   //res.message = response.message;
  }
 });

}
```

In the ***api.ts*** I am receiving all the values as undefined.
Whats wrong with my code?

Thank You.

Comment: Could you provide more code of ```server.ts``` file? Especially ```app.use()``` entries.

Comment: @MaciejSobala Hello, I have updated the `server.ts` file, thank you.

Comment: Does the answer works for you?

Comment: @MaciejSobala I just got home, I will try it now, Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing bodyParser in your server-side code.
Perform following actions:

`npm install body-parser --save`

In your server.ts:

```
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import * as express from 'express';

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

/*
other code
*/
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Have been struggling for days to solve this.

Comment: That's great. So now you can accept and vote for this answer :)

Comment: One thing you should do before I do that, `app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));` should be called before `app.post("/api/send", sendMailApi);` in the `server.ts` file , then it worked for me. Please update the answer, this tiny detail can save a lot of time for someone new like me.